# Map entity pagination class to dto pagination class

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following PaginatedList class.

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; }
    public int TotalPages { get; }

    public PaginatedList(IEnumerable<T> items, int totalRecords, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalRecords = totalRecords;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(TotalRecords / (double)pageSize);

        AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage => PageIndex > 1;

    public bool HasNextPage => PageIndex < TotalPages;

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(
        IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

I'm using this class to get pagination information for list of entity that is retrieved with EF.

This is how I use this class to return list of users with pagination info.

```
var users = await PaginatedList<User>.CreateAsync(userQuery, pageIndex, pageSize);
```

Above call will return `PaginatedList<User>` object.

If I have a DTO class for that entity, let's call it `UserDto`. How do I use automapper to convert `PaginatedList<User>` into `PaginatedList<UserDto>` so the result will have all userDto objects and also the pagination info?

Otherwise, is there another/better way to achieve something similar?

Comment: Deriving from `List<T>` is an extremely poor choice.  I highly recommend reading [Is-A Versus Has-A](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/isa-versus-hasa1).

Comment: @ErikPhilips thanks for the suggestion, I'll take a look

Comment: @ErikPhilips Why is deriving a bad choice? I think PaginatedList is a List, but with additional attributes.

Comment: @user3049658 [Why not inherit from List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193).  There are properties `PageIndex` on THIS questions implementation that are not *what a list nor paginatedlist* is.  `PageIndex` is property of a State, not a property of a List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating another factory method within the PaginatedList which will handle the conversion.

```
public static async Task<PaginatedList<TResult>> CreateAsync<TSource>(
    IQueryable<TSource> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    Ensure.It.IsGreaterThan(0, pageIndex);
    Ensure.It.IsGreaterThan(0, pageSize);

    var count = await source.CountAsync();
    var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .Select(ufc => Mapper.Map<TResult>(ufc))
        .ToListAsync();
    return new PaginatedList<TResult>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```

Then make the existing `CreateAsync` method to call this new `CreateAsync<TSource>` method.

```
public static async Task<PaginatedList<TResult>> CreateAsync(
    IQueryable<TResult> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    return await CreateAsync<TResult>(source, pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```

With this, if we want to keep returning the same Entity class, we can use it like this

```
await PaginatedList<User>.CreateAsync(_dbContext.User.AsQueryable(), pageIndex, pageSize)
```

And if we want to convert the entity class to return a Dto class or other class, it can be used like this

```
await PaginatedList<UserDto>.CreateAsync(_dbContext.User.AsQueryable(), pageIndex, pageSize)
```

If we don't convert the Entity into other class, we don't need to specify anything within the automapper configuration. But if you want to map the entity into other class, then it needs to be configured within the automapper.

More or less, here is how the PaginatedList class looks like

```
public class PaginatedList<TResult> : List<TResult>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; }
    public int TotalPages { get; }

    public PaginatedList(IEnumerable<TResult> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalRecords = count;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(TotalRecords / (double)pageSize);

        AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage => PageIndex > 1;

    public bool HasNextPage => PageIndex < TotalPages;

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<TResult>> CreateAsync<TSource>(
        IQueryable<TSource> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .Select(ufc => Mapper.Map<TResult>(ufc))
            .ToListAsync();
        return new PaginatedList<TResult>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<TResult>> CreateAsync(
        IQueryable<TResult> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        return await CreateAsync<TResult>(source, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Automapper is perfect for me, but are going to need to create and default constructor on the `PaginatedList` class

```
public PaginatedList()
{
    PageIndex = 0;
    TotalRecords = 0;
    TotalPages = 0;
}
```

-------------------------------- Example

```
class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class UserDto
{
    public string NameDto { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile: Profile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
            .ForMember(target => target.NameDto, x => x.MapFrom(source => source.Name))
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}

internal class Program
{
   private static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Mapper.Initialize(config =>
       {
           config.AddProfile<UserProfile>();
       });

       var items = new List<User> { new User { Name = "First name" } };

       var users = new PaginatedList<User>(items, 1, 0, 1);

       var usersDtos = Mapper.Map<PaginatedList<UserDto>>(users);

   }
```

}